# Clickhouse compatibility between different versions for Merge tables

Tags: compatibility, clickhouse

I have a question regrading compatibility between different Clickhouse server versions. I have a ReplicatedMergeTree Table Engine, let's call it Table A on Clickhouse server version 20.3. I have another Replicated MergeTree Table Engine, let's call it Table B on Clickhouse server version 21.8. I have a Merge Table Engine, let's call it Table C, running on Clickhouse server version 20.3 which merges data from Table A and Table B. Since the different tables are on different versions of Clickhouse, I wanted to know whether there would be any issues because of it.

In short
Node 1 (version 20.3) - Local Table A.
Node 2 (version 21.8) - Local Table B.
Node 3 (version 20.3) - Distribute Table A, Distributed Table B, Merge Table C(of Distributed Table A and Distributed Table B)

Is it supported by Clickhouse or not?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it supported by Clickhouse or not?

Not in general. Distributed queries over different versions may produce incorrect results. I know 2 issues for this case with 20.3 + 21.8.

Also I don't understand how you going to use Engine=Merge, you need Distributed table to query remote server. And I think you don't need Engine=Merge. It's a simple 2 shards schema for Distributed table.

Anyway, I don't recommend to use it. But it's possible and will work with limited usecases.